# Ajax modal popup with modal binding from within partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find a solution for a while but could not find one... I have partial view which is bound to a modal and it displays data in grid. Something like below

```
@model abc
@Html.Grid(Model)
{
    grid columns
    column with edit link
}
```

on the click of edit link from a grid, through ajax, I would want to display popup window in partial view which is bound to another model. This bootstrap popup window should also be bound through model binding as I need to perform server side validations when click on Submit of popup

```
@model pqr
<div>
   popup window with grid columns displayed in form for editing.
</div>
```

Any help with sample code would help tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways to do this but I have done like this before:

1. Your edit link must have id as the id to be passed as param to Controller
2. Get data and pass the model to the partial view with properties populated

   ```
   $(".YourEditLinkClass").click(function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
         url: "@Url.Action("GetDataForPopUpWindow", "YourController")",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "html",
         data: { id: id },
         success: function (data) {
             $("#modal_" + id).html(data);//target position of modal
             $('#pqr_' + id).modal('toggle');
           }
        });
   });
   ```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetDataForPopUpWindow(int id)
{
   using (YourDBContext)
   {
      var data = YourData;
      pqr pqrModel = new pqr();
      pqrModel.YourModelProperty = data.CorrespondingProperty;
      return PartialView("_GridPartialView", pqrModel);
   }
}
```

Your bootstrap modal must have the id as `id="pqr_@Model.Id"` in the partial view called _GridPartialView. Hope it makes sense.